# How to create and update data in different tables in the same time - Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel-9, laravel-query-builder

I have a 2 tables pasiens and beds. What I want to do is when I add a new data in 'pasiens', as well as update in 'bed' table. Here is my PasiensController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // return ($request);
    $request->validate([
        'nama' => 'required',
        'jk' => 'required',
        'alamat' => 'required',
        'nik' => 'required|unique:pasiens',
        'no_telp' => 'required|unique:pasiens',
        'no_rm' => 'required|unique:pasiens|max:8',
        'status' => 'required',
    ]);

    $query = pasien::create([
        'nama' => $request->input('nama'),
        'jk' =>$request->input('jk'),
        'alamat' => $request->input('alamat'),
        'nik' => $request->input('nik'),
        'no_telp' => $request->input('no_telp'),
        'tgl_masuk' => date(now()),
        'no_rm' => $request->input('no_rm'),
        'status' => $request->input('status'),
        'id_bed' => $request->input('id_bed')
    ]);

    $bed = bed::find($request->input('id_bed'))->update([
        'status_bed' == 1
    ]);
    // return $query;
    // return $bed;
    return back()->with('berhasil', 'Data telah ditambahkan');        
}
```

I have try to make like this but it is doesn't work, can anyone help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is with the update -- instead of using `==` you should use `=` to set the `status_bed` to 1

```
$bed = bed::find($request->input('id_bed'))->update([
    'status_bed' => 1
]);
```

you may want to consider handling potential errors that may occur during the database operations
use `try-catch` to handle potential errors that may occur during DB operations (exception is caught -- display an error message to user with details)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'nama' => 'required',
        'jk' => 'required',
        'alamat' => 'required',
        'nik' => 'required|unique:pasiens',
        'no_telp' => 'required|unique:pasiens',
        'no_rm' => 'required|unique:pasiens|max:8',
        'status' => 'required',
    ]);

    try {
        $query = pasien::create([
            'nama' => $request->input('nama'),
            'jk' =>$request->input('jk'),
            'alamat' => $request->input('alamat'),
            'nik' => $request->input('nik'),
            'no_telp' => $request->input('no_telp'),
            'tgl_masuk' => date(now()),
            'no_rm' => $request->input('no_rm'),
            'status' => $request->input('status'),
            'id_bed' => $request->input('id_bed')
        ]);

        $bed = bed::find($request->input('id_bed'))->update([
            'status_bed' => 1
        ]);

        return back()->with('berhasil', 'Data telah ditambahkan'); 
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return back()->with('error', 'An error occurred while adding data: '.$e->getMessage());
    }       
}
```